# how to implement localization in React-native app

Tags: react-native, localization, translation, i18next, react-i18next

I want to implement localization in my React Native project , I know I can use i18n but My translation file is little different as bellow. I am not sure how to implement this. These files are being used in my Angular website and I am trying to use the same in my React native App, So I can not change bellow files.

en.json

```
[
    {
        "term": "modal.alert.close",
        "definition": "Close",
        "context": "",
        "term_plural": "",
        "reference": "",
        "comment": ""
    },
    {
        "term": "has-expired",
        "definition": "<ph name=\"INTERPOLATION\"><ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}<\/ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}<\/ph> has expired.",
        "context": "",
        "term_plural": "",
        "reference": "",
        "comment": ""
    },

]
```

de.json

```
[
    {
        "term": "modal.alert.close",
        "definition": "Schlie\u00dfen",
        "context": "",
        "term_plural": "",
        "reference": "",
        "comment": ""
    },
 {
        "term": "has-expired",
        "definition": "<ph name=\"INTERPOLATION\"><ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}<\/ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}<\/ph> ist abgelaufen.",
        "context": "",
        "term_plural": "",
        "reference": "",
        "comment": ""
    },
]
```

Comment: Feel free to see my blog post that covers this: 
https://stefan-majiros.com/blog/implementing-react-native-localization-like-a-pro/

Comment: thank you , but I had problem with the interpolation syntax which was extracted by Angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
"definition": "<ph name=\"INTERPOLATION\"><ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}<\/ex>{{alert.uniqueId}}<\/ph> has expired.",
```

above string contains different syntax which is extracted by Angular i18n. so it is not supported by react native i18n parser yet.

for this scenario you have to use extractor which are available for react native.